# Event.preventDefault() in Wordpress Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, forms, api, maps, submit

I've already asked this question over at the Wordpress forum, but got no response. I saw several posts about changing it to a 'return false', but no luck either. I'm currently trying to generate directions through the Google Maps API v3. I want to combine this with Contact Form 7 in Wordpress. When a user submits the form, I want to calculate the directions between point A and point B.

The input field id's are grabbed through a JS file and hooked to the API. When I press submit, Contact Form 7 generates the failure to send message.

The inside of my form looks like this:

```
<div id="calculate-route">[submit "Send"]</div>
```

This is in the JS file:

```
$("#calculate-route").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
calculateRoute($("#from-point").val(), $("#to-point").val());
});
```

Any ideas why event.preventDefault() isn't working? I enqueued the JS script succesfully in the footer. Using a plain HTML form generates the map and directions properly.

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: any console errors? sounds like '$' is undefined ....

Comment: @David
Thanks for your question. I get the following console error:

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
     $(document).ready(function() {
        // If the browser supports the Geolocation API
        if (typeof navigator.geolocation == "undefined") {
          $("#error").text("Your browser doesn't support the Geolocation API");
          return;
        }`

Comment: try replacing "$" with "jQuery" wp uses this by default.

Comment: Thanks David, that seems to solve the console errors. On the other hand, I still can't submit the 2 locations, because I still get the Contact Form 7 error. Any ideas?

Comment: what error is it showing?

Comment: "Message couldn't be sent, try again later or seek another method." It's the default message I think, loosely translated from my native language.

Comment: you will have to look into that, its not a js error, try on the contact form support forum

Comment: Okay, I will. Thanks ;).

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the code was inside a contact form 7 div which was probably colliding with other code. Made a page template with a shortcode which I added in the contact form.